How to translate a string and then slice it in the template
I am working on an Angular application and need to display a translated string that is sliced to a specific length. My supervisor prefers that all logic that related to view better to be implemented directly in the view (template), without modifying the component (controller) code.
attempted to chain the translate and slice pipes in the template, but it did not work as expected:
Here is the full code:
<span 
ng-if="vm.yaxis[vm.yaxis.length-1-yIndex].label.length > 10" 
class="y-label tooltipped" 
data-tooltip="{{vm.yaxis[vm.yaxis.length-1-yIndex].label | translate}}" 
data-position="bottom">
    {{(vm.yaxis[vm.yaxis.length-1-yIndex].label | translate) | slice: 0 : 8}}
    <span class="y-label-dots">...</span>
</span>

It actually checked the yaxis label length and if length is greater than 10 the label should be slice. but the problem is this will not show any label in the interface. it show as blank. if i do slice and translate then this not translate correctly since in the i18n translation files does not contain string that slice. therefore I need to apply the translate and then slice.

what version of angular do you have? Did I understand correctly that span exists, but it is empty?

This question is about AngularJS, as indicated by ng-if and "Controller" terminology

Could you try ng-init and assign the value to a local variable translated, then perform the translation.
<span 
ng-if="vm.yaxis[vm.yaxis.length-1-yIndex].label.length > 10" 
class="y-label tooltipped" 
data-tooltip="{{vm.yaxis[vm.yaxis.length-1-yIndex].label | translate}}" 
data-position="bottom">
    <span  ng-init="translated = (vm.yaxis[vm.yaxis.length-1-yIndex].label | translate)">
        {{translated | slice: 0 : 8}}
        <span class="y-label-dots">...</span>
    </span>
</span>


The question was labelled incorrectly, it's a question about an AngularJS application
